# Mouse click events - mouse coordinates on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I wanted to find out the co-ordinates of the mouse click event on the page. Wrote a little piece of JS which works well on Chrome but not on Firefox. Seems the default global 'event' is not available in Firefox. Here is a smaller version of the code that worked on Chrome:

```
 $("body").click(function() {
    if (event == undefined)  // for Chrome, 'event' is not undefined here
        var event = window.event;           
    var xx;
    var yy;
    if (event) {
    // Need this for Chrome (and IE)
        xx = event.x;
        yy = event.y;
    } else {  
      // firefox 
      // WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?
    }
    console.log('Click called on body.' + xx + ':' + yy);
}
```

What should I manage the Firefox case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery (which it looks like you are using) sorts out the event parameter versus global `event` property issue for you, so you don't need to worry about that. It also normalizes `pageX` and `pageY` properties.

```
$("body").click(function(evt) {
    var xx = evt.pageX;
    var yy = evt.pageY;

    console.log('Click called on body.' + xx + ':' + yy);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery passes the event as the first argument to your click handler.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to pass the event as a parameter. Use the below format, and do a console.log(e) to get all the data associated with it. But I'm not sure it has x and y coordinates, you might have to get the coordinates of the element it clicked.

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
}
```

EDIT: pageX and pageY seem to be provided, along with a bunch of others...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event variable in the click function call e.g.

```
.click(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```